# add/subtract/or multiply as per the given string

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, stack

I was given this problem in an interview, return the output of this String s = "4+8×2" , output = 20, Ex2: String s = "3×7-4", output = 17.
This is my approach, but I am not able to get the expected result, please point out the correct way here.

```
 public static int findResult (String s) {
        int i = 0;
        Stack<String> stack =  new Stack<>();
        while (i < s.length()) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '+') {
                stack.push(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
                i++;
            } else if (s.charAt(i) == '*') {
                stack.push(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
                i++;
            } else if (s.charAt(i) == '-') {
                stack.push(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
                i++;
            } else if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                int num = s.charAt(i) - '0';
                while (i+1 < s.length() && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i + 1))) {
                    num = num * 10 + s.charAt(++i) - '0';
                }
                stack.push(String.valueOf(num));
                i++;
            }
        }
        int current = 0;
        //second while loop
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
            if (stack.isEmpty()) return current;
            String sign = stack.pop(""
            //int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
            if (sign.equals("*")) {
                current = firstNumber * Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                stack.push(String.valueOf(current));
            }
            else if (sign.equals("-")) {
                current = firstNumber;
                stack.push(String.valueOf(current));
            } else {
                current = firstNumber + Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                stack.push(String.valueOf(current));
            }
        }

        return Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
    }
```

Comment: If last op is not lower precedence, then perform it before pushing this op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I approached this problem. (It is somewhat similar to yours). I'll post the code first, then explain the process below:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(findResult("2*57-38*3/5-5-2+3*4/2-2-2"));
  }
   public static double findResult (String s){
     String sub = s;
     ArrayList<Double> nums = new ArrayList<Double>();
     ArrayList<Character> operations = new ArrayList<Character>();
     for(int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++){
       if(s.charAt(x) == '+' || s.charAt(x) == '-' || s.charAt(x) == '*' || s.charAt(x) == '/' ){
         operations.add(s.charAt(x));
         int subInd = sub.indexOf(s.charAt(x));
         nums.add(Double.valueOf(sub.substring(0,subInd)));
         sub = sub.substring(subInd + 1);
       }
      }
     nums.add(Double.valueOf(sub));
     String[] operationTypes = {"*/","+-"};
     for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < operations.size(); j++){
           if(operationTypes[i].indexOf(operations.get(j)) != -1){
             double val;
             if(operations.get(j) == '*'){
              val = nums.get(j) * nums.get(j+1);
             }
             else if(operations.get(j) == '/'){
              val = nums.get(j) / nums.get(j+1);
             }
             else if(operations.get(j) == '+'){
              val = nums.get(j) + nums.get(j+1);
             }
             else{
              val = nums.get(j) - nums.get(j+1);
             }
             nums.set(j,val);
             nums.remove(j+1);
             operations.remove(j);
             j--;
           }
         }
       }
    return nums.get(0);
  }
}
```

Yeah...it's a lot:

The first step in this process was to divide the String into two `ArrayLists`: `nums` and `operations`. `nums` stores the terms and `operations` stores the..operations (*, /, +, -).

Now, we iterate through each "group" of operations, that being multiplication and division, and addition and subtraction.

Starting with mult/div, if we see either a `'*'` or `'/'` in our `operations`, then we compute the product or quotient of the corresponding elements in our `nums` and edit `nums` accordingly by modifying the element that matches indexes with the operation and deleting the term following it. Make sure you also remove the operation from nums and decrement the counter variable so the loop does not skip any values.

Finally, we will return the only value left in our `nums` which will be our answer.

I hope this helped you! Please let me know if you need any further details or clarification :)

Comment: This works on test cases, thank you so much for the code. But this is O(n2) solution, I am just trying to figure out if there is a better way.

Comment: This solution is only O(2n) = O(n) I believe? There are two for loops but the outer one only repeats twice. Let me know if I’m mistaken

Comment: @SimmiDutta I just double checked, yes this is an O(n) solution. I believe that this is the fastest complexity since we have to evaluate every term.

Comment: Thanks. Is this because of 2 sets of operations we are looping the first for loop twice?

Comment: Yes, since it only runs twice no matter the input size it it still an O(1) operation